# Docker: mapping container UID to an "non-existing" UID on host

Tags: linux, docker, namespaces

I am tinkering with Linux namespaces to better understand how Docker (or rather, runc) interacts with them.
By default, Docker does not create a *user namespace* for a container, meaning that UID `0` inside the container also means UID `0` on the host.

One way to bridge this potential security issue is to change the UID under which the processes inside a container are run by using, either the `USER` instruction inside a Dockerfile, or the `--user` flag in Docker CLI.

From what I understood, the UID assigned to the container (e.g. via `USER` inside a Dockerfile) must match the same existing UID on the host (i.e. the UID must exists in `/etc/passwd` and GID in `/etc/group`)

So I ran an experiment and created a Dockerfile with the following content:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN groupadd -r -g 1001 appuser
RUN useradd -r -u 1001 -g appuser appuser

USER appuser

ENTRYPOINT ["sleep", "infinity"]
```

On the host machine, there is no user with a UID of `1001` nor a group with a GID of `1001`. Yet to my surprise, when I ran the container then `ps aux | grep sleep`, the `sleep infinity` process from the Docker container showed up and the associated username was not a name but rather  the corresponding UID, `1001`.

So my questions are: how is it possible to ask for container's processes to run under a UID that the host has no knowledge of? And, how does the kernel checks for permissions if it has no knowledge on that UID (e.g. does it create a temporary unprivileged user for that purpose) ?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you're incorrect. The UID and GID does not need to be in the host /etc/passwd. If you use a nonexisting username, the UID will just show up as owner. It's a perfectly legal thing to do.

I like to do it like this:

```
FROM whatever
ARG UID=80
ARG USER=user
RUN useradd -u $UID $USER && mkdir /deploy /logs && chown -R $USER:$USER {/deploy/,/logs/}
USER $USER
```

To answer your questions:

1. How is it possible to ask for container's processes to run under a UID that the host has no knowledge of?

As above.

2. How does the kernel checks for permissions if it has no knowledge on that UID (e.g. does it create a temporary unprivileged user for that purpose) ?

If a UID has no permissions, then it has no permissions.
For example, imagine a file with chmod 770, group root:users. Both user root and anyone in group users has read write and execute. A user with an unknown UID will have permission 0 on that file, which means that it cannot read, write or execute (see) that file.

Now imagine a file with chmod 777. User, group and anyone has rwx permissions now. This means that even if the user is unknown and thus has no permissions, it still gets to access and execute this file.

That's why you never ever set chmod 777 on anything. and generally avoid more than read permissions for the third bit that represents the "anyone" group.